# Integrating Facebook, Twitter, FriendFeed, Picasa and other Social Media or Networking Sites in to a website

Tags: facebook, twitter, picasa, google-buzz, friendfeed

Iam developing a website in PHP, which has to integrate facebook, twitter, friendfeed, picasa etc..

Is there a common API using which we can integrate various famous social networking sites like facebook, twitter and etc. So that If i post a comment in my site, that should be sent to all the registered social sites. That is with a single button click i want to write to my wall in facebook and tweet to my twitter account.

Or should i use the social networking sites individual APIs to achieve this.

Please suggest me...

Comment: As on my site (http://www.appsmerge.com) we use the different API's, i don't think you can find one Libary / API to access all these different web applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use AddThis and am very happy with it!

http://www.addthis.com/

But with regard to sharing all at once I don't believe there is, but AddThis does centralise everything nicely making your job a little easier!

Failing that you can use this app:

http://hellotxt.com/

Looks very promising!